# VSE: How to render a video with audio?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, audio

I want to play a music strip with a video in the video editor but the video has no music when I play it.  I've rendered it but it still doesn't have sound.  How can I render and play the video with the sound track.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. We need more information in order to solve your problem. For instance: do other sound clips play properly? Have you tried reencoding the sound clip in a different format? Maybe you could provide a screenshot of your sequence and settings? These, and any other details, will help people to give you a helpful answer.

Comment: Please add at least a screen shot of you render settings / output. Which audio codec do you use? Do you hear the music when played in Blender? Did you try to play the video in another player like VLC?

Answer (score 14):

In blenders preferences under system you have a few options for the software used for sound, this may help playing sound from blender's VSE.

[image]

For the output video you need to check that you have selected an audio codec in the encoding options.

[image]

Comment: Any idea why I can't get sound even after setting the audio codec?

Comment: Where can I find the second image, how do I get to the "Output" options?

Comment: @Michael the output settings are part of the [render output](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/output/properties/output.html) settings which you can find in the [properties editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/properties_editor.html)

Answer (score -3):

In video Editor, in the left side. Edit Strip / Sound.
volume. now volume is 1. go up to 100...

Comment: Please expand/clarify your answer. Screenshots can help future viewers as well.

Comment: volume max is 1.0  not 100.